# Altering raster values without using ArcPy

Tags: python, raster, gdal, landsat-8

I'd like to be able to alter raster values, through fairly simple equations, without using the module ArcPy.

Is that possible?

It seems like gdal, numpy, and rasterlang might make this possible but I'm having trouble figuring out exactly how.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the type of operations you'd like to carry out and the languages you already know... `Python`-`gdal` or `R` (with the `raster`  library) are good open source solutions.

Since it seems you're more into Python, [here](http://www.gis.usu.edu/~chrisg/python/2009/) is a good place to start -- especially lessons 4-6.

Here is a small example of applying a threshold to a raster:

```
import os, sys, numpy, gdal
from gdalconst import *

os.chdir('path/to/your/raster')

# register all of the GDAL drivers
gdal.AllRegister()

# open the image 
inDs = gdal.Open('my_raster.img', GA_ReadOnly)
if inDs is None:
  print 'Could not open my_raster.img'
  sys.exit(1)

# get image size
rows = inDs.RasterYSize
cols = inDs.RasterXSize

# read the input data
inBand = inDs.GetRasterBand(1)
inData = inBand.ReadAsArray(0, 0, cols, rows).astype(numpy.Float)

#simple raster algebra
outData = numpy.where(inData >= 5, 10, 0)

# create the output image
driver = inDs.GetDriver()
outDs = driver.Create('highpass1.img', cols, rows, 1, GDT_Float32)
if outDs is None:
  print 'Could not create highpass1.img'
  sys.exit(1)
outBand = outDs.GetRasterBand(1)

# write the output data
outBand.WriteArray(outData, 0, 0)

# flush data to disk, set the NoData value and calculate stats
outBand.FlushCache()
stats = outBand.GetStatistics(0, 1)

# georeference the image and set the projection
outDs.SetGeoTransform(inDs.GetGeoTransform())
outDs.SetProjection(inDs.GetProjection())

inDs = None
outDs = None
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but you must know Python (and not just ArcPy):

You can use [osgeo/gdal](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/GdalOgrInPython), [rasterio](https://github.com/sgillies/rasterio), [Python raster stats](http://blog.perrygeo.net/2013/09/24/python-raster-stats/)  or [pyresample](http://code.google.com/p/pyresample/), for example, in combination with others scientific Python modules as Numpy, SciPy, and ...

There are lots of examples on the Web but to begin, look at

- [Geoprocessing with Python using Open Source GIS](http://www.gis.usu.edu/~chrisg/python/2009/) (Chris Garrard University course at Utah State University)
- The [Python GDAL/OGR Cookbook: Raster Layers](http://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/raster_layers.html) (Jared Erickson)
- The books  [Python Geospatial Development](http://www.packtpub.com/python-geospatial-development/book) (Eric Westra)  and [Learning Geospatial Analysis with Python](http://geospatialpython.com/2013/11/geospatial-python-book.html) (Joel Lawhead).